# Script continues if error occurs in && and set -e is used

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

If in a script I use `set -e` the script continues after an error has occurred in a statement that executes two commands with `&&`.

For example:

```
set -e

cd nonexistingdirectory && echo "&&"
echo continue
```

This gives the following output:

```
./exit.sh: line 3: cd: nonexistingdirectory: No such file or directory
continue
```

I want the script to exit after `cd nonexistingdirectory` and stop.

How can I do this?

** Edit**
I have multiple scripts using `&&` that I need to fix to make sure they exit upon error. But I want a minimum impact/risk solution. I will try the solution mentioned in the comments to replace `&&` with `;` combined with `set -e`.

Comment: [BashFAQ/105](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) seems relevant; see Exercise 3

Comment: Don't use `&&` as a shortcut then, use a regular `if` statement.

Comment: If you are using `set -e` (which I don't recommend), just replace `&&` with `;`. `echo "&&"` won't execute if the script is aborted due to an error from `cd`.

Comment: If `set -e` didn't have an exception for nonzero exit status that was branched on, you couldn't ever handle an error manually (`cd foo || { echo "ERROR: bar must be run before this script"; exit 1; }` wouldn't print the error message, because the script would have exited the moment the `cd` failed). Even worse, `if grep -e foo bar; then ...; else ...; fi` would never hit the `else`, because the shell would exit when `grep` had a nonzero exit. That making it usable requires making it nonintuitive is part of why `set -e` should never be used by anyone.

Comment: contructs which evaluate success or failure effectively consume a failure so that you can programatically respond to local events while still setting global traps for uncaught exceptions. As a rule, I always try to make any uncaught error a fail with a trap to report it and exit appropriately, and then explicitly catch and handle the ones I expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is your `&&` command.

In fact, when a command that retrieves error is executed together (`&&`) with another command, the `set -e` doesn't work.

If you explain better the real use case we could find out a work around that fits your needs.

> `set [+abefhkmnptuvxBCEHPT] [+o option] [arg ...]`
>
> `-e`      Exit immediately if a pipeline (which may consist of a single simple command),  a subshell command enclosed  in  parentheses,  or
>                         one of the commands executed as part of a command list enclosed by braces (see SHELL GRAMMAR above) exits with a non-zero status.
>                         **The shell does not exit if the command that fails is part of the command list immediately following a  while  or  until  keyword,
>                         part of the test following the if or elif reserved words, part of any command executed in a &&** or || list except the command fol-
>                         lowing the final && or ||, any command in a pipeline but the last, or if the command's return value is being inverted with !.

from `man bash`

Comment: This should mention the `set [-abc...] [-o option]` line, no? `set +e` turns the option *off*.

Answer (score 4):

This is by design. If you use `&&`, bash assumes you want to handle errors yourself, so it doesn't abort on failure in the first command.

Possible fix:

```
set -e

cd nonexistingdirectory
echo "&&"
echo continue
```

Now there are only two possibilities:

1. `cd` succeeds and the script continues as usual.
2. `cd` fails and bash aborts execution because of `set -e`.